# Format drive without terminal

Tags: partitioning, mount, gnome-terminal, format

I want to format my HDD to NTFS to install windows, but dev/sda1 is failing to unmount because "device is busy". However, when I try to open terminal and force an unmount it flashes open and immediately closes, same thing with UXterm and Xterm. The tty screens do the same thing, after login something flashes and it returns to the enter username screen. Is there anyway to format the HDD with recovery mode in Grub, which seems to be the only place I can actually run commands?

Answer (score 1):

sda is where the system is, you can not dismount. Give Boot with a liveCD and use Gparted to format